# How to add one view to another view which is created using java file that extends view/

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is what i am trying to do, this my main class file
private View `TicTacStart`;

//onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TicTacStart = new Game(this);
    //reference to base layout..
    LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);


    //I cant INFLATE THE VIEW SINCE I AM NOT USING XML AND RATHER USING ANOTHER CLASS GAME WHICH EXTENDS VIEW 
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View thisScreensView = vi.inflate(TicTacStart, null);



    //add the view to the base view...
    baseView.addView(thisScreensView);
}
```

This is game class

```
public class Game extends View {

    private Cell[][] singlesquare = null;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 3;
    private int l;
    private int a;
    private boolean whatdrawn = false;
    private int playerwin = 3;
    private Paint caneta;

             Data Data  MORE classes
 }
```

so basically what I want to do is add Game view class into `baseview` in my main class file. Is there someway i can make this work as i don't want to use xml's now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuu can directly add GameView into baseview for ex:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TicTacStart = new Game(this);
    //reference to base layout..
    LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);

    baseView.addView(TicTacStart );
}
```

Comment: Why do we even use layout inflater then ? #Just curious

Comment: inflater is used to convert your xml layout into view object.

Comment: Thank you.I am just trying to learn online looking at newer codes and devloping experience.

Comment: if you have an xml that contained GAME tag and wanted to add that instead of creating it's object dynamically in java class u will have to use inflater

Comment: Ya i get that know . :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again how do i use my code if i want to use fragments ?          @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState){

Comment: onCreateView returns a view so you can simply write:---- return new Game(container.getContext());

Comment: Sorry but what about inflater ?

Comment: if your fragment only has GameView then you don't need an Inflater to inflate it